# Complex Logic- Finding Renewals on Licenses

Tags: sql, mysql-logic

Need help in querying the below logic:

I have to calculate renewals. An org can order up to 5 licenses in total from us

License Table 2018

| Year | Licenses |
| --- | --- |
| 2018 | A |
| 2018 | A |
| 2018 | B |
| 2018 | B |
| 2018 | C |
| 2019 | A |
| 2019 | A |
| 2019 | B |

License Table 2019:

| Year | Licenses |
| --- | --- |
| 2019 | A |
| 2019 | A |
| 2019 | B |

Result:

| License | Renewal Percentage |
| --- | --- |
| A | 100% |
| B | 50% |
| C | 0% |

More conditions:

Suppose the 2 order dates are 6/30/2019 and 7/1/2020, which are in FY19 and FY21 respectively. Even though the 2nd order is barely more than 1 year later, it is not treated as a renewal.

Comment: Sample data and the desired output would help.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, just added the sample input and result. Would really appreciate your help.

Comment: `Licenses Renewed` doen't look as a table really. Could you share the table structure?

Comment: Its not really a table like I presented, but its the same table like the first table, with two licenses for A and one license for B. I just added a more concise structure of the same first table. But I have made the edits for your better understanding. Thanks